# How do I stop Liquibase updateSQL from generating Start and successful messages that end up in the SQL?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

This command:

```
 liquibase --logLevel=off --changeLogFile=./database_change_log.xml --url='offline:postgresql?outputLiquibaseSql=true' updateSql > database_up.sql
```

generates this:

> ```
> Starting Liquibase at Thu, 14 Mar 2019 11:29:12 CDT (version 3.6.3 built at 2019-01-29 11:34:48)
>
> -- *********************************************************************
>
> -- Update Database Script
>
> -- *********************************************************************
>
> -- Change Log: ./database_change_log.xml
>
> -- Ran at: 3/14/19, 11:29 AM
> -- Against: null@offline:postgresql?outputLiquibaseSql=true
> -- Liquibase version: 3.6.3
> -- *********************************************************************
>
> CREATE TABLE databasechangelog (ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED INTEGER NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM VARCHAR(35), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), COMMENTS VARCHAR(255), TAG VARCHAR(255), LIQUIBASE VARCHAR(20), CONTEXTS VARCHAR(255), LABELS VARCHAR(255), DEPLOYMENT_ID VARCHAR(10));
>
> -- Changeset ./database_change_log.xml::1::Jim Barrows
>
> CREATE TABLE topic (id UUID NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, description TEXT, CONSTRAINT TOPIC_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (id));
>
> INSERT INTO databasechangelog (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES ('1', 'Jim Barrows', './database_change_log.xml', NOW(), 1, '8:7b01de4dcdab4ed25f79ce192ba538f6', 'createTable tableName=topic', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '3.6.3', '2580954069');
>
> Liquibase command 'updateSql' was executed successfully.
> ```

The problem is that I don't want the "Starting liquibase" or success lines in the SQL.

Note: off is from the docs: --logLevel=  Execution log level (debug, info, warning, severe, off).

I've tried to use "severe" & "error" as well

This is version 3.6.3, and version 3.5.3 does not do this.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Ayup.  off is documented.  I tried error just in case though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone has already opened a bug ticket for this: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3342.

This [seemingly got introduced](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/commit/c32c4f6a5b6edd2558a2802bac9077f7985b3f9d) from version 3.6 on.

**EDIT:**

<s>So maybe downgrade or even better propose a fix in form of a pull request. :-)</s>

Wondering about why `updateSQL` output would be written with a logging framework
I just discovered that you could pass in [migrationSqlOutputFile](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/generated/updateSQL-mojo.html#migrationSqlOutputFile) as a parameter instead of redirecting the standard output to a file. That way the logging should not be mingled with output from `updateSQL`.

(Have not tried this though.)

Comment: This is for maven plugin. Do you know gradle equivalent?

Comment: No, I don't. But maybe this should be fixed in liquibase directly instead of "finding a way around it with a config in maven". The ticket ist still open in liquibase Jira.

Answer (score 1):

Use --outputFile option in the liquibase command to direct the sql statements to a file. I use liquibase version 3.7.0 and this option works.

Answer (score 0):

Since 3.4.0 release of Liquibase, you can use `outputFile` flag. Details are here:
https://www.liquibase.org/2015/07/without-a-connection.html